# How to dynamically access dictionary attribute in Python?

Tags: python

How would you go about editing a dictionary as an object attribute? Right now I have I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Generic_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = default_dict.copy()
        self.attr2 = default_dict.copy()
        self.attr3 = default_dict.copy()
        self.attr4 = default_dict.copy()
        ...
```

I am (trying) to do it this way so that I can access the dictionaries as part of an instance of this class, and there could end up being hundreds of different instances. I would like to be able to access the attributes dynamically because the attribute to be accessed is determined by data that is retrieved by the program at run-time. These dictionaries are also going to be edited possibly hundreds of times so something like

```
attr_name = 'This is dynamic'
instance_dict = default_dict.copy()
instance_dict['a key'] = 'value'
setattr(x, attr_name, instance_dict)
```

wont work because I need previous edits to remain. Since I need to access the attributes dynamically I can't use `x.y['key] = 'value'`, but I cant edit the dictionary using `setattr()` so I am not sure what to do.

Comment: This question makes no sense. Can you create a [mcve] to show the actual error you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to "level up" in the abstraction.  These hundreds of dicts should all be stored as the *values* in one outer dict.  When the attribute names would be coming from *data*, don't use attributes at all - use keys.

So rather than this:

```
attr1 -> dict1
attr2 -> dict2
attrn -> dictn
```

You will have this:

```
myattr ->  {key1: dict1,
            key2: dict2,
            keyn: dictn}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)?

```
inst = Generic_class()

attr_name = "this is dynamic"
instance_dict = getattr(inst, attr_name, None)

if instance_dict is None:
    # this attribute doesn't exist, so create it as empty dict
    instance_dict = default_dict.copy()
    setattr(inst, attr_name, instance_dict)
```